# Nested EditorFor with TemplateName

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, editorfor

I have this `ViewModel`

```
public EmployerViewModel
{
    public List<EmployerHelper> Employers { get; set; }
}

EmployerHelper
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    //...
    public List<WageHelper> { get; set; }
}
```

In the `ViewEmployers.cshtml`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Employers)
```

In the `EditorTemplates\EmployerHelper.cshtml` I have:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ID" />

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Wages, "EmployerWageHelper")
```

However, when I try to run this setup I am getting:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...ViewModels.Helper.WageHelper]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type '...ViewModels.Helper.WageHelper'.

The question is why is the first `EditorFor` working as expected, ie passing the `List<EmployerHelper>` to the `EditorTemplate` one at a time. However, the second `EditorFor` is passing the whole `List` of `WageHelper` to the `EditorTemplate`, instead of one at a time, as expected. What did I miss?

When I do the `EditorFor(x => Wages)` (without the `template` name) it works fine. However, I can not use that because there is another `template` for  `WageHelper` used for a different method. Am I misunderstanding how the `templateName` `override` of `EditorFor` works or is this some kind of a bug in `Razor`?

(For now I've had to create an `EmployerWageHelper` which is a duplicate of `WageHelper` to get around this problem.)

Comment: The error already showed that you have trying to pass `List<ViewModels.Helper.WageHelper>` collection instead of strongly-typed `ViewModels.Helper.WageHelper` into view. Since you didn't provide controller code yet, it's hard to tell where the error comes from.

Comment: The controller code is irrelevant here, however if you really want it: `public IActionResult ViewEmployers() => View(new EmployerViewModel());` Your comment also shows that you did NOT take the time to actually read my question. I am well aware that it is passing a `List`, but as I asked in the OP... WHY? Why is it passing a list? I am expecting it to pass one at a time as is happening in the previous `EditorFor`